# can't install pygame using pip, Python 2.7.6 on Win7

Tags: python, pygame, pip

I've installed Python 2.7.6 (32-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit). This works fine in Windows Power Shell. I set the PATH to `C:\Users\name\Python27\Scripts`, and that didn't seem to be a problem either. I then downloaded a pygame install file, `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win32.whl`, from:

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame
```

I put the .whl file into the Python27\Scripts directory, and tried using `pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win32.whl` in Windows Power Shell (command line, not Python interpreter), and the error message is this:

`The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

I tried using Python 2.7.8 (the later version of Python 2.7, if I'm not wrong) with an .msi install of pygame, but I experienced other errors with this that I thought could be fixed with a fresh install. I am very new to programming and using the command line; any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

you must not have set the path variable in windows..it's the same mistake that i made..

set the environment variable in windows by doing fallowing steps:

1. right click 'My Computer'
2. go to properties
3. Advanced System Settings
4. Environment Variables
5. and set Path there..

if this doesn't help then try another method :

1. open your python installation directory
2. goto Tools
3. Scripts
4. Run "win_add2path.py"

Now try to run  `$) pip install, commd`..

if it still doesn't work .. restart your console or restart the PC

@shub1493biswas@gmail.com